# jQuery - find selector for html input array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck with finding jQuery selector for these elements:

```
<input name="products[5][quantity]">
<input name="products[5][price]">
<input name="products[13][quantity]">
<input name="products[13][price]">
```

I need to find all products (price and quantity to multiply them) and sum that (it's price to cart), like sum_of_all_products( price * quantity = price_for_one_product)

I saw manual https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ , but this need a little bit more skill.

Can somebody gives me clue please?

Comment: try this to get all product elements. `$("[name^='products']")` , but from where you need to get the `price` and `quantity`. I can see only one number there ..

Comment: to get the number the name string use this `$("[name^='products']:first")[0].name.match(/\d+/)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be simpler to do the calculations

```
<input class="products" data-id=5 data-key="quantity">
<input class="products" data-id=5 data-key="price">
<input class="products" data-id=13 data-key="quantity">
<input class="products" data-id=13 data-key="price">
```